# How to edit a bezier path in xcode after view loads

Tags: xcode, path, draw, bezier

I need to be able to update the three points of my bezier path in xcode after the view has loaded.I would like to update my bezier path by a NSTimer. I am able to draw the initial bezier path, but I can't figure out how to change it after the initial loading! I am making a slingshot, so that's why I need to change my bezier path often. ANY Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`NSBezierPath` is an immutable path. Rather than changing an existing one, you need to create a new one with the updated points.

Comment: How can I erase the previous path?

Comment: You can start with `[NSBezierPath appendBezierPathWithRect:[view frame]];` and fill it with the background color.